# c++ template specialization and derivation

Tags: c++, templates

When using template like this:

```
class A {…}
class B : A {…}
class C : A {…}

template<typename T>
class D{…}
```

I need T can only be B or C. Which means T must be a derivation of A.

Is there any way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `std::is_base_of` along with `std::enable_if`:

```
template<typename T, typename X = std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<A, T>::value>::type>
class D{...}
```

Note that it will accept any `T` as long as it derives from `A`. If you need `T` to be either `B` or `C`, then you need to modify it, and use `std::is_same` or/and `std::conditional` along with `std::enable_if`.

You could make it clean as:

```
template<typename T, typename Unused = extends<T,A>>
class D{...}
```

where `extends` is defined as:

```
template<typename D, typename B>
using extends = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<B,D>::value>::type;
```

---

`static_assert` can also be used (like other answers have shown) if you want it to result in error and compilation failure. However if you need selection or deselection, say from many specializations, then use the above approach.

Hope that helps.

Comment: why not `static_assert`?

Comment: That can be also be used if you want it to result in error and compilation failure. However if you need selection, then `std::enable_if`.

Comment: I would prefer `static_assert`, because it's cleaner and guaranteed. With above solution, think about `D<int, void> d;` A user can bypass it (un)knowingly.

Comment: @iammilind: As I said, the solutions are not equivalent. So it is not about mere *preference*. It is about *design*.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) in combination with [`std::is_base_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of):

```
#include <type_traits>

class A {};
class B : A {};
class C : A {};
class X{};

template<typename T>
class D
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<A,T>::value, "T must be derived from A");
};

int main()
{
    D<C> d_valid;
    D<X> d_fails; // compilation fails

    return 0;
}
```

[<kbd>live on ideone</kbd>](https://ideone.com/NqjNJV)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) should do it:

```
template<typename T>
class D {
 static_assert(std::is_base_of<A,T>::value, "not derived from A");
 // ...
};
```

[Demo here.](http://ideone.com/iO3Gjv)

**But** this is not the idea behind templates. If you write templated code, then it should be generic, I.e. work for all types that support the operations that you apply on them.

Comment: Well, it is legitimate write generic code that makes assumptions on the generic type T. All the fuss about 'concepts' is about how to introduce this in the language.

Comment: Indeed, but there's already support  to model assumptions that can be put into some hierarchical order: the "is-a" relationship of inheritance. Of course inheritance won't always do, but I'd guess that this is not such a case. Concepts are more about "cross cutting" properties, like being moveable but not copyable.